# How to use strerror_r so compiler does not complain about ignoring return value?

Tags: c++

I have some library code that makes sure a file does not already exist. As it was library code I thought it was worth the effort to check for other error codes and report them:

```
struct stat statBuf;
if(::stat(fname.c_str(), &statBuf) == 0){
    LOG(ERROR) << "The file (" << fname << ") already exists. BAD.";
    return ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
    }    

if(errno != ENOENT){
    char errorBuf[512];
    strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511);
    LOG(ERROR) << "The file (" << fname << ") does not exist, but stat-ing gave an error (" << errorBuf << ").";
    return ERROR_BAD_FILENAME;
    }
```

All was good until we tried an `-O3` build, instead of a debug build, and get:

```
error: ignoring return value of ‘char* strerror_r(int, char*, size_t)’,
declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
```

The reason I don't directly use `strerror_r()` in the LOG line is for portability; [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r) says it could return `int` or it could return `char*`.

I have tried the cast trick:

```
(void)strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511);
```

or:

```
static_cast<void>( strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511) );
```

But still just get:

```
error: ignoring return value of ‘char* strerror_r(int, char*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
     (void)strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511);
```

My best idea so far is:

```
auto dummy = strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511);dummy = dummy;
```

The `dummy = dummy` bit is to stop the complaint about an unused variable. :-)

(By the way, I am not even sure what the "XSI" mentioned in the linux manual is - perhaps it is the kind of portability I will never need??)

Comment: Re: XSI http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html

Comment: Err, don't ignore the return value?

Comment: @EJP Err, why? 
(In both versions of the function the information I am after is written into the buffer I give, so I have no interest in the return value. And in the XSI version of the function the return value is another error code - the only possible error is the buf I gave was not big enough, and errno gets set in that case anyway.)

Comment: Since you know how to silence the warning, I vote for this question to be closed. Note that you may want to check the return value for errors (the ones mentioned in the manual page you linked to).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thanks for having the manners to explain the downvote :-) My question was about the correct way to use `strerror_r()`. Is my `auto dummy = strerror_r(errno, errorBuf, 511);dummy = dummy;` monstrosity really the best code?!

Comment: Pay more attention to the documentation: the GNU version (returning a pointer) does not promise to store the string in the buffer provided. You ***must not*** ignore the return value if using the GNU version.

Comment: @hvd Curses, you are right! This function is more of a pain than I thought - so do I need to use `#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE` and have two versions of my function?

Comment: I'd say pick one version and stick with it. If it appears in a header, create a wrapper function and use that instead. This way, users of your library don't have to worry about macro definitions, but you get the version you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-Wno-unused-result` option.

Alternatively you may temporarily disable and then re-enable a particular warning if you're absolutely sure that it doesn't cause any harm. [Here's the corresponding GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If it was one-off code I would consider that, but not really an option for library code, where a user might want to be compiling with that warning on.